# PHP HTML table is overflowing into next div

Tags: javascript, css, cakephp, html-table

I've recently started working on someone else's CakePHP project, it's a search page which displays a filter table to the left and results to the right. The footer is right below. My problem is that there are a few rows where I want only 1 td instead of 3 as he's done. But as soon as I remove the 2 tds/add a nested table with only 1 td/make a separate table/move the trs around, the table starts overlapping the footer. What could be wrong? There's some Javascript behind the filter table too but I'm not too good with JS so I'm kind of stuck. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Give the table's container `overflow: hidden` or give the footer `clear: both`. Also, try giving examples from your code in your next question.

Comment: `colspan="3"` springs to mind. You need to post your code.

Comment: It will be better if your post screenshot of problem you are facing

Comment: It will be best if you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).